# SCIP - can't map file, errno=22

Tags: compilation, scip

I'm trying to install last version of scip from its official website to use Normaliz on Mac OS X. But , I get the error,

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file './/lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build failed with GMP=true: if GMP is not available, try building with GMP=false (note that this will deactivate Zimpl support)
```

and When I compile it again I get

```
Soners-MacBook-Pro:scip-3.2.0 soner$ make ZLIB=false GMP=false READLINE=false
/Users/soner/Documents/scip-3.2.0/make/make.project:329: ZIMPL was deactived because of missing GMP support.
-> linking bin/scip-3.2.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file 'lib/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build failed with GMP=false and LPS=spx: use GMP=true or make sure that SoPlex is also built without GMP support (make GMP=false)
```

I tried like `make ZLIB=false GMP=true READLINE=false`. Even same with `GMP=true`.

How can I install it successively?

@Edit, verbose result is [on the link](https://jpst.it/177h6).

---

Soplex 3.0 - `make` - terminal run and output:

```
Soners-MacBook-Pro:soplex-3.0.0 soner$ make COMP=gnu GMP=false
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/enter.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/gzstream.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/leave.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/ratrecon.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solvedbds.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solverational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solvereal.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplex.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplexlegacy.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxautopr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxbasis.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxboundflippingrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxbounds.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxchangebasis.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdantzigpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdefaultrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdesc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdevexpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxequilisc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxleastsqsc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxfastrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxfileio.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxgeometsc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxharrisrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxhybridpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxlpbase_rational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxlpbase_real.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxmainsm.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxparmultpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxquality.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxscaler.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxshift.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsolve.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsolver.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxstarter.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsteeppr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsumst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxvecs.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxvectorst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxweightpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxweightst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxwritestate.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/statistics.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/testsoplex.o
-> generating library lib/libsoplex-3.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/bin/soplexmain.o
-> linking bin/soplex-3.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt
Soners-MacBook-Pro:soplex-3.0.0 soner$
```

Soplex 3.0 - `sudo -s make install INSTALLDIR=/usr/local` result,

```
Soners-MacBook-Pro:soplex-3.0.0 soner$ sudo -s make install INSTALLDIR=/usr/local
Password:
-> install SoPlex headers into INSTALLDIR </usr/local>
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/changesoplex.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/clufactor.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/clufactor_rational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/enter.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/leave.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/rational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/ratrecon.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/slufactor.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solvedbds.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/slufactor_rational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solverational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/solvereal.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplex.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/soplexlegacy.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxautopr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxbasis.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxboundflippingrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxbounds.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxchangebasis.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdantzigpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdefaultrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdesc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxdevexpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxequilisc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxleastsqsc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxfastrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxfileio.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxgeometsc.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxharrisrt.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxhybridpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxlpbase_rational.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxlpbase_real.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxmainsm.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxparmultpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxquality.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxscaler.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxshift.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsolve.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsolver.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxstarter.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsteeppr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxsumst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxvecs.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxvectorst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxweightpr.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxweightst.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/spxwritestate.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/statistics.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/updatevector.o
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/testsoplex.o
-> generating library lib/libsoplex-3.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
-> compiling obj/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/bin/soplexmain.o
-> linking bin/soplex-3.0.0.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt
-> install SoPlex libraries into INSTALLDIR </usr/local>
-> install SoPlex binary into INSTALLDIR </usr/local>
Soners-MacBook-Pro:soplex-3.0.0 soner$
```

Scip 4.0 error on terminal

```
    Soners-MacBook-Pro:scip-4.0.1 soner$ make ZLIB=false READLINE=false GMP=false
    make/make.project:481: ZIMPL was deactived because of missing GMP support.
    -> generating necessary links

    - Current settings: LPS=spx2 OSTYPE=darwin ARCH=x86_64 COMP=gnu SHARED=false SUFFIX= ZIMPL=false ZIMPLOPT=opt IPOPT=false IPOPTOPT=opt EXPRINT=cppad GAMS=false

    * SCIP needs some softlinks to external programs, in particular, LP-solvers.
    * Please insert the paths to the corresponding directories/libraries below.
    * The links will be installed in the 'lib/include' and 'lib/static' directories.
    * For more information and if you experience problems see the INSTALL file.

      -> "spxinc" is the path to the SoPlex "src" directory, e.g., "<SoPlex-path>/src".
      -> "libsoplex.*" is the path to the SoPlex library, e.g., "<SoPlex-path>/lib/libsoplex.linux.x86.gnu.opt.a"

    > Enter soft-link target file or directory for "lib/include/spxinc" (return if not needed): 
    > /usr/local
    -> creating softlink "lib/include/spxinc" -> "/usr/local"


    > Enter soft-link target file or directory for "lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a" (return if not needed): 
    > /usr/local
    -> creating softlink "lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a" -> "/usr/local"

    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_allfullstrong.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_cloud.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_distribution.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_fullstrong.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_inference.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_leastinf.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_mostinf.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_multaggr.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_nodereopt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_pscost.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_random.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch_relpscost.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_abspower.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/compr_largestrepr.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/compr_weakcompr.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/concsolver_scip.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_and.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_bivariate.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_bounddisjunction.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_cardinality.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_conjunction.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_countsols.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_cumulative.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_disjunction.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_indicator.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_integral.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_knapsack.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_linear.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_linking.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_logicor.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_nonlinear.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_or.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_orbitope.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_pseudoboolean.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_quadratic.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_setppc.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_soc.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_sos1.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_sos2.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_superindicator.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_varbound.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_xor.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons_components.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/dialog_default.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/event_softtimelimit.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/disp_default.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/event_solvingphase.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_sync.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/event_globalbnd.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_sync.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_actconsdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_bound.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_clique.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_coefdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_completesol.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_crossover.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_dins.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_distributiondiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_dualval.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_feaspump.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_fixandinfer.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_fracdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_gins.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_guideddiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_indicator.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_intdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_intshifting.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_linesearchdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_localbranching.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_lpface.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_locks.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_mutation.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_multistart.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_nlpdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_objpscostdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_octane.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_ofins.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_oneopt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_proximity.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_pscostdiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_reoptsols.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_repair.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_randrounding.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_rens.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_rins.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_rootsoldiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_rounding.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_shiftandpropagate.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_shifting.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_simplerounding.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_subnlp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_trivial.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_trivialnegation.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_trysol.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_twoopt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_undercover.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_vbounds.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_veclendiving.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_zeroobj.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur_zirounding.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/message_default.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_bfs.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_breadthfirst.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_dfs.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_estimate.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_hybridestim.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_restartdfs.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/nodesel_uct.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_boundshift.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_convertinttobin.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_domcol.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_dualagg.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_dualcomp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_dualinfer.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_gateextraction.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_implfree.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_implics.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_inttobinary.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_qpkktref.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_redvub.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_trivial.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_tworowbnd.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/presol_stuffing.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_dualfix.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_genvbounds.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_nlobbt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_obbt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_probing.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_pseudoobj.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_redcost.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_rootredcost.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/prop_vbounds.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_bnd.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_ccg.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_cip.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_cnf.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_diff.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_fix.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_fzn.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_gms.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_lp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_mps.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_mst.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_opb.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_osil.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_pip.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_pbm.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_ppm.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_rlp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_sol.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_wbo.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/reader_zpl.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_cgmip.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_clique.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_closecuts.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_cmir.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_convexproj.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_disjunctive.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_eccuts.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_flowcover.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_gauge.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_gomory.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_impliedbounds.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_intobj.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_mcf.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_oddcycle.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_rapidlearning.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_strongcg.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/sepa_zerohalf.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/boundstore.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/branch.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/clock.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/concsolver.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/concurrent.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/conflict.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/conflictstore.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cons.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cutpool.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/cuts.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/debug.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/dialog.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/disp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/event.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/fileio.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heur.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/heuristics.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/compr.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/history.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/implics.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/interrupt.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/intervalarith.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/lp.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/matrix.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/mem.o
    -> compiling 
        // There some other compiling just I remove because of message limitation stackoverflow
obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/dijkstra/dijkstra.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/lpi/lpi_spx2.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/bitencode.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/blockmemshell/memory.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/scip/message.o
    -> generating library lib/static/liblpispx2-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/tpi/tpi_none.o
    -> generating library lib/static/libtpinone-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/nlpi.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/nlpioracle.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/expr.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/nlpi_ipopt_dummy.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/intervalarithext.o
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/nlpi/exprinterpret_cppad.o
    -> generating library lib/static/libnlpi.cppad-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
    -> compiling obj/static/O.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt/bin/main.o
    -> linking bin/scip-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2.none
    ld: can't map file, errno=22 file './/lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a' for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    build failed with GMP=false and LPS=spx2: use GMP=true or make sure that SoPlex is also built without GMP support (make GMP=false)
    Soners-MacBook-Pro:scip-4.0.1 soner$ make ZLIB=false READLINE=false GMP=false
    make/make.project:481: ZIMPL was deactived because of missing GMP support.
    -> linking bin/scip-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2.none
    ld: can't map file, errno=22 file './/lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a' for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    build failed with GMP=false and LPS=spx2: use GMP=true or make sure that SoPlex is also built without GMP support (make GMP=false)
    Soners-MacBook-Pro:scip-4.0.1 soner$ make ZLIB=false READLINE=false GMP=false
    make/make.project:481: ZIMPL was deactived because of missing GMP support.
    -> linking bin/scip-4.0.1.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.spx2.none
    ld: can't map file, errno=22 file './/lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a' for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    build failed with GMP=false and LPS=spx2: use GMP=true or make sure that SoPlex is also built without GMP support (make GMP=false)
    Soners-MacBook-Pro:scip-4.0.1 soner$
```

Comment: Did you try `GMP=false`?

Comment: Is `./lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a` a proper file or symlink to a proper file? If so, then include the full output of your make call when adding also `VERBOSE=true`

Comment: @Gerald yes, same.

Comment: Ok. Please check that lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a points to the soplex library or is a copy of the soplex library, as stefan suggests.

Comment: There is no static folder in lib directory? @stefan

Comment: I've edited it @Gerald

Comment: Can you just start the build of SCIP from scratch, that is remove the whole thing, then unpack and rebuild. And then post the complete log from that build. Obviously, something went wrong in the beginning of the make run where the softlinks to SoPlex are set.

Comment: What is your idea Mr.@stefan?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just specify `/usr/local` for the two links that should be created. `lib/include/spxinc` should point to a directory, where the SoPlex headers are, which is probably something like `/usr/local/include/soplex` and `lib/static/libsoplex.darwin.x86_64.gnu.opt.a` should point to the library itself, so probably  `/usr/local/lib/libsoplex....`, see the output during the compilation process.

If you want to make your life easier and since you probably downloaded the SCIP optimization suite anyway, you can just call `make` and `make install` in the root directory of the optimization suite and it will compile SCIP, Soplex, and ZIMPL and also set the links as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should give CMake a try. This usually works better on non-Linux systems. Have a look here for information on how to use CMake: http://scip.zib.de/doc/html/CMAKE.php

Concerning your error message: It seems that the SoPlex library was not successfully built or at least cannot be found when trying to link SCIP.